# How can I convert from YYYY-MM-DD on datetime64 to MM-DD and plotting tips

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, datetime64

I have a database from COVID that I'm playing with.
I have info in the format YYYY-MM-DD and I'm plotting days vs. number of cases in a bar plot.
In my graph, the days appear as months, but I want an axis with every 7 days.
Should I convert my datetime64 format to MM-DD and plot my graph?

This is the code I'm using to plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
ax.bar(x0, y0, color='green')

ax.set(xlabel = 'Data da notificação', 
       ylabel = 'Casos novos')

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 45)

plt.show()
```

And this is the resulted graph:

[image]

This is the graph I want:

[image]

Sample data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4Njy0mGMtIeEABdaFrzNEMSavjpXtlUn8BM8z_QZBk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add some sample data so we can reproduce the graph?

Comment: Done! It is at the end of the question

Comment: I would also like to fix these weird limits of the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format like `MM-DD`, you can specify `fmt` argument which accepts a strftime format string for formatting and is a required argument to the `DateFormatter`.

You can also specify an `interval` argument to the `DateLocator`. e.g. `interval=7` the locator places ticks at every 7th date.

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


df = pd.read_csv("1.csv", delim_whitespace=True)

df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

ax.bar(df['data'], df['casosNovos'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%m%d'))

ax.set_xlim(df['data'].min(), datetime.date(2020, 8, 21))

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 45)

plt.show()
```

[image]

`1.csv` looks like

```
regiao  data    casosNovos
Brasil  2/25/2020   0
Brasil  2/26/2020   1
Brasil  2/27/2020   0
Brasil  2/28/2020   0
Brasil  2/29/2020   1
Brasil  3/1/2020    0
Brasil  3/2/2020    0
Brasil  3/3/2020    0
```

Comment: Cool! How do I limit the x axis in datetime? The axis extends to dates that do not exist in the database.

Comment: @EduardoValentindosSantos Use `ax.set_xlim()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!